# Meteor observe not working properly in 1.6

Tags: meteor

I recently upgraded from 1.2 to Meteors latest version 1.6.0.1.

I was using observe in a publication and an observe on the client to get changes.

in 1.2 no problems at all, but in 1.6 observed changes are not received in a "changed" client callback, but the client does get the ddp message. I can verify that by looking in Chromes dev tools > websocket, see the incoming message, but it's never fired in a client callback. This only happens when changing 2-3 documents at a time.

So when I delete a few documents from the DB, the publication fires off the callbacks, and the client receives them in the websocket messages, but it only fires once in the "observe" callback on the client.

Here is my code.

Client -

```
CollectionTest = new Meteor.Collection('collectionTest');


CollectionTest.find({}).observe({
   added: function (doc) {
      console.log("ADDED DOC ", doc);
   },
   changed: function (newDoc, oldDoc) {
      console.log("CHANGED DOC new ", newDoc);
   },
   removed: function (doc) {
      console.log("REMOVED DOC ", doc);
   }
});
```

Server Publication -

```
Meteor.publish("ddpPub", function () {

    var self  = this,
        ready = false;

    var userId = self.userId;

    var subHandle = TestData.find({}).observeChanges({
        added: function (id, fields) {
            if (ready) {
                self.changed("collectionTest", userId, {
                    type: "added",
                    data: {
                        id: id,
                        fields: fields
                    }
                });
            }
        },
        changed: function (id, fields) {
            if (ready) {
                self.changed("collectionTest", userId, {
                    type: "changed",
                    data: {
                        id: id,
                        fields: fields
                    }
                });
            }
        },
        removed: function (id) {
            if (ready) {
                self.changed("collectionTest", userId, {
                    type: "removed",
                    data: id
                });
            }
        }
    });

    self.added("collectionTest", userId);
    self.ready();
    ready = true;

    self.onStop(function () {
        subHandle.stop();
    });
});
```

Attached are images from me removing the documents from the DB. The websocket messages, and then my console on the client. Showing it only fires once for 5 documents.

[Showing the document id's I am deleting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IlJEX.png)

[DDP messages in 'websocket' confirmed they get to client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9PEe.png)

[Single client message in client callback showing only document changed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZaGh.png)

UPDATE: 12/15/17 - 7:17pm PST

After working on this for a couple hours, finding some related meteor posts with observe callbacks and “Meteor.call” not working inside, the solution or hack is to wrap the “Meteor.call” in a “setTimeout” with the value of 0, and it fixes it.

I tried that here, and it didn’t work, but then I tried throttle the response, and it works! Not sure if it's a reliable fix, but it's the only one I found so far.

I am not sure why this works, or what causes the problem in the first place, any explanation would be welcome.

Server Publication -

```
Meteor.publish("ddpPub", function () {

    var self  = this,
        ready = false;

    var userId = self.userId;

    var subHandle = TestData.find({}).observeChanges({
        added: function (id, fields) {
            if (ready) {
                console.log("ADDING PUBLICATION");
                self.changed("collectionTest", userId, {
                    type: "added",
                    data: {
                        id: id,
                        fields: fields
                    }
                });
            }
        },
        changed: function (id, fields) {
            if (ready) {
                console.log("CHANGING PUBLICATION");
                self.changed("collectionTest", userId, {
                    type: "changed",
                    data: {
                        id: id,
                        fields: fields
                    }
                });
            }
        },
        removed: function (id) {
            if (ready) {
                console.log("REMOVING PUBLICATION");
                ratePub(id, function (data) {
                    console.log("OBJECT DATA IS ", data);
                    self.changed("collectionTest", userId, data);
                });
            }
        }
    });

    self.added("collectionTest", userId);
    self.ready();
    ready = true;

    self.onStop(function () {
        subHandle.stop();
    });
});

var returnPub = function (id, callback) {
    console.log("RETURNING PUB ");
    callback({
        id: id,
        type: "removed",
        data: id
    });
};

var ratePub = _.rateLimit(returnPub, 10);
```

Comment: You should take your answer and post it as an answer instead of as an update to the question. Otherwise this looks like an unanswered question.

Comment: Hey Michel, I didn't want to post my initial answer as a solution just because I felt is was a temporary work around to a problem that I didn't understand. Now there is a answer because we found was was causing it, and have an actual proper fix.